# AsyncPLayer pauses with "INFO/AwesomePlayer(37): cache is running low" log

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am using an AsyncPlayer to stream music from an URI and when testing the app on an android 4 emulator, I am getting an couple of pause and resume sequences generated by:

```
03-14 17:17:51.926: INFO/AwesomePlayer(37): cache is running low (1.96 secs) , pausing.
03-14 17:17:51.936: WARN/MediaPlayer(548): info/warning (703, 0)
03-14 17:17:51.936: INFO/MediaPlayer(548): Info (703,0)
03-14 17:17:51.946: WARN/MediaPlayer(548): info/warning (701, 0)
03-14 17:17:51.946: INFO/MediaPlayer(548): Info (701,0)
03-14 17:17:52.976: INFO/AwesomePlayer(37): cache has filled up (7.42 secs), resuming.
```

Did anyone encounter this issue, how can I avoid low cache pauses?

Thanks

Comment: Have a good network connection?

Comment: Yeap, the network connection is not an issue. Actually it pauses and resumes a couple of times when the radio starts and then it runes ok. But it can get annoying for the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a network issue, the issue come from your bandwidth.

The value of the enum : **MEDIA_INFO_NETWORK_BANDWIDTH = 703**

**src**: http://androidxref.com/source/xref/frameworks/base/include/media/mediaplayer.h at line 107